# Laravel: Array to String

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

It is my code in which I get the subcategories' names. But the problem is it shows data in an array form.

```
$couponCategory = Coupon::select('categories')->where('expiry_date', '>', $dt)->where('status', 1)->first();
$couponsCat = explode(',', $couponCategory);

$categoriesDetails = Category::select('category_name')->whereIn('id', $couponsCat)->whereNotIn('parent_id', [0, 0])->get()->toArray();
str_replace("'", "\'", json_encode($categoriesDetails));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($categoriesDetails);
die;
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category_name] => Casual T-Shirts
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category_name] => Formal T-Shirt
        )

)
```

I also try to convert it into a string but the output is like

```
[{"category_name":"Casual T-Shirts"},{"category_name":"Formal T-Shirt"}]
```

I want the result just display the name **Casual T-Shirts and Formal T-Shirt no brackets or anything in string formate**

Comment: Its an array, treat it like an array

Comment: possible way to display in simple string??

Comment: `foreach($categoriesDetails as $cat) { echo $cat['category_name']; }`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Through simple debugging, it should be possible to check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pluck` to get just the field you want in a basic array format:

```php
$categoryNames = Category::whereIn('id', $couponsCat)
  ->whereNotIn('parent_id', [0, 0])
  ->pluck('name');
```

Then loop over the results, either using blade of plain old PHP.

```html
@foreach ($categoryNames as $name)
  {{ $name }}
@endforeach

foreach ($categoryNames as $name) {
  echo $name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel collections can be imploded easily:

```php
echo $categoriesDetails->map->category_name->join(' ');
```